# Error(34,0): project with path ':libs' couldn't be found in project ':app'

Tags: android, android-studio

When i am changing my sdk platform tool, there is a problem in the configure, the error shown here is project with path ':libs' could not found in project ':app'. I am currently using android studio 3.0 canary 6.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhmdE.png)

following image shows the actual problem that i am facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can config on build.gradle like this
[image]

Comment: ../libs it mean this libs folder located in parent tree - not the same level

Comment: build.gradle means in build.gradle(project) ?

Comment: it like your image upload

Comment: Cannot get property 'utilDependencies' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

Comment: Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: I can not help you anymore.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code / config as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.